# SSIS Azure Blob Download Task - Method not found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am getting below error when I tried to download files from Blob container.  I can upload files to the same subfolder but unable to download file.  TLS1.2 is enabled on the computer.  Anyone experience this issue with a solution?

[Azure Blob Download Task] Error: Download task has stopped with exception: Method not found: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.AzureBlobConnectorHelper.CreateBlobClient(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)'.

[image]

Comment: Are you tried to download the blob through azure portal?

Comment: I am trying to download files from Azure portal with SSIS Azure Blob Download Task in SSIS.  I can use the Azure Blob Upload Task to upload the files from local directory on my computer to Azure portal.  However, the download is giving me above error when I execute the Azure Blob Download Task within SSIS.